# ListViewItem is Null for some reason

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datatable, listviewitem

This is the error I got whenever I tried to populate my ListView with "users" collection using DataTable returned from a repository function that communicates with MySQL database. Note that `item` is defined as `ListViewItem` in my code:

[error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tlsy.png)

The weird thing is, other databases can be populated into the ListView successfully where even null value cells are also checked with the following code:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

                table = repo.displayHistory()
                Dim dr As DataTableReader
                dr = table.CreateDataReader
                Dim a As String = "null"

                If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    Do While dr.Read
                        Dim item As New ListViewItem(dr(columnNames(0)).ToString) 'this is ID column
                        For j As Integer = 1 To repo.getColumnCount - 1
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr(columnNames(j)).ToString) Then
                                item.SubItems.Add(a)
                            ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr(columnNames(j)).ToString) Then
                                item.SubItems.Add(dr(columnNames(j).ToString))
                            End If
                        Next
                        lstOrderHistory.Items.Add(item)
                    Loop
                    lstOrderHistory.View = View.Details
                End If
```

Therefore, the code is able to populate NULL value cells with a string named "null"
However, the table named "users" is the only table that has the abovementioned error. Even in repository file, I also tried to test `displayHistory()` function where the core code is as shown below:

```
If IsNothing(tableName) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a table name.")
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Try
                MySqlConn.Open()
                sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " & tableName & ";"  'tableName is public property that reads table name from user
                dttable = MysqlClient.DataHandler.GetDataTable(sqlstr, conn, True)
                If Not IsNothing(dttable) Then
                    If dttable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("table is filled!")
                        Return dttable
                    ElseIf dttable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("table is empty!")
                        Return Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
```

For this part, all tables will show either "table is filled" or "table is empty" where "users" table never even triggered any of these two messages. I suspect that the sql command itself was hanging but timeout never occurred (maybe i didnt wait long enough)

What should i do to fix this error?

Comment: Don't use a `ListView` in the first place. It's not a grid control. Populate your `DataTable` and bind it to a `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`. Two lines of code and you're done, instead of all that messing around.

Comment: @John im not confident whether this can solve this but i'll get back to you again once i implement it

Comment: Given that a `DataGridView` doesn't use `ListViewItems`, it definitely will solve this particular issue. There may be other issues or details that need ironing out but you can't fail to correctly create an item if you're not creating the items. You simply bind, which is setting one property, and all the columns and rows will be created automatically. If you need more control then you can have it but it's still less fiddly than a `ListView`.

Comment: Just tried it, and you are 120% right
thank you so much